# meaning of scheme theoretic - defining equation

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In algebraic geometry, an algebraic set $X$ is the common zero set of polynomials.
In this case, these polynomials is called the defining equation of $X$.
I know that any algebraic set regards as scheme by Hartshorne book (II.2.6).

My question is simple... what is the meaning of scheme theoretic - defining equation??

Answer (score 3):

It means that you keep track of the actual polynomials in the defining ideal, as opposed to just the reduced portion (the radical of the ideal).  For example, $x$ and $x^2$ define the same zero set in $k[x,y]$, but scheme-theoretically, the schemes corresponding to $k[x,y]/(x)$ and $k[x,y]/(x^2)$ are not the same.

Comment: then scheme theoretic defining equation of the zero set of $x^2$ is $x$?? and so to find scheme theoretic defining equation any algebraic set is to find the generator of its ideal??

Comment: No... if you only know the zero set, you have already lost too much information to determine what the scheme theoretic defining equation is.  You need more information.  For example, the intersection of the parabola $y=x^2$ and the line $y=0$ is defined by the ideal $(y, x^2)$ - those are the scheme theoretic equations.  But you can't determine this if you only know the point of intersection (0,0).  Can you give some context about where you are reading this?

Comment: I don't read to this for some book. I hear this in seminar.... in studying for rational normal curve.. someone ask what is the scheme theoretic defining equation for rational normal curve.